# Не получается изменить отступы в макете (Android)

Tags: android, xml

Имеется xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".ArticleActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/article"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Вроде бы стоят отступы, но почему-то текст растягивается на всю ширину. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том что расположение вьюх в ConstraintLayout происходит с помощью различных привязок. В твоем случае ты задал отступы для TextView, но не задал к чему привязана твоя TextView (и как следствие не понятно от чего ей отступать).
Пример привязки к родительскому блоку:

```
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Но это еще не все. У твоей TextView ширина задана как "wrap_content" и при таком раскладе margin все равно не будет корректно работать, в таком случае можно задать заместо margin - padding или задать ширину TextView - 0dp (match constraint)

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```